# Including CSS and Ruby tags in Object field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, object, view

If this has been answered, please provide a link. I had no luck searching here or Google.

I have a Content model with identifier, title and description fields. I can use `Content.find_by(identifier: "privacy-policy").description` in my app/views/privacy.html.erb using Ruby tags, and this allows me to edit Privacy policy's content directly from the app, rather than hardcode it into the view file.

My question is, how do I enable CSS styling and Ruby tags in the Content model's description field? If say, I needed to write `"I <b>accept</b> the privacy policy <%= Time.zone.now %>"`

Or is there another approach or best practise of doing this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Shopify's [Liquid markup language](http://liquidmarkup.org/) was designed for allowing end users to write their own dynamic view code, so check that out if those are your requirements.

If it's not going to be edited by end users and you're not worried about security, you can pass parse the ERB yourself with `ERB.new(content).result`.

If you don't need dynamic ruby and just want end-user content editor (simple styling etc), I would recommend using a [markdown parser](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/markup_processors).

Comment: It will be edited by admins only (before_filter in ContentsController) so I'm leaning towards parsing the ERB myself (I'm not a fan of large gems) but exactly what security vulnerabilities would this introduce? I could write horrible code directly from production that would cause memory issues or production to crash?

Comment: ERB parses ruby so ... you can do write whatever Ruby you like. Use your imagination.